# Access Keycloak database in its source code

Tags: sql, database, keycloak, h2, keycloak-services

I have created a new table in Keycloak's H2 Database (called MyTable) and I want to read that table and also execute some sql commands in the ValidateUsername.java of Keycloak source codes.

Does anyone have any idea that how can I have an access to the database in the source code of Keycloak?

Comment: Hi, did you find out eventually?

Comment: @Barnercart Hi, yes. You have to make some changes in the source code. Start with the jpa model project (SourceCodeDir/model/jpa). By checking out the implementation of entities like UserEntity.java, you will find out how to start changing the source code. Note that I had to change model/infinispan, server-spi and also the services modules in the source code

Comment: thanks for the headsup! Do you have any tangible example I could look in to to understand these concepts better?

Comment: @Barnercart. Not really. I've searched a lot but couldn't find a good example. So I've done it by myself.